# Subdomain onestep checkout is redirecting to main domain cart page

Tags: cart, magento1.9.2.4, domain

Only in mobile, when I click on sub domain onestep `checkout` page, it gets redirected to main domain `cart` page.

And its working fine in desktop version, facing issue only in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

check following things

Might be your mobile checkout page is coming from different theme, so enable template path hint and check

Might be that template file has a static link

Comment: coming from same file. It started happening after enabling SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Go to `admin section -> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management`
Hit Add URL Rewrite button

```
Select at Create URL Rewrite: Custom
Set at Request Path * = old checkout path
Set at Target Path * = new chekout path
Set at Redirect = Permanent (301)
Save
```

Refresh magento cache